# Why doesn't the chime work on my GE Profile double oven?

Tags: oven

The chime on my older GE Profile double oven stopped working.  I turned off the breaker and after 2 minutes turned it back on.  The chime started working again but after 1 day went off again.  I tried several other hacks posted by others but the chime will still not work.  Using cook timer, it counts down to 0:00 but no beep.  Pushing buttons no beep.  Any suggestions?  MODEL PB975TP1WW

Comment: Perhaps the beeper component on the board has fried (or baked).

Comment: If you cycle power again does the chime return, or is it done for good now?

Comment: What setting is the chime volume at? If you change that does it have an effect?

Comment: First, assume the chassis of the oven is electrically energized.  Seriously. Now, check - does the oven light work?  If the oven light is working, forget my "electrically energized" warning - if it's not working, then take it very seriously as the oven neutral may have a problem. Very few things on an oven use neutral, but when neutral breaks, *if the oven connection is 3-wire*, that can shock.

Comment: What trouble shooting steps have you tried beyond "turn it off and on again"? "Several other hacks" isn't very descriptive... Have you unplugged the oven then opened it up to look for burnt wiring or fried electronics?

Comment: I turned the power off the 1st time and the chime came back up for a short time.  The 2nd time I power cycled the pver the chime lasted less than 15 seconds.  I have pushed every combination from various hacks to set the chime volvume to no avail.  My next step is to pull the top cover to view the control boards.  ALL other options on the stove are working as they normally would including lights.